# Selecting the "lowest" items in a 2d array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array - it's populated with `1`s and `0`s.

When "rendered" out - it looks like this:
[image]

Basically, I would like to select the lower sections (highlighted in red). Is there anyway to select just the lowest `1`s?

Thanks again!

**[edit]**
I should mention that the lowest points are random each time!

**[edit2]**
Currently I'm just selecting everything below a certain area and seeing if it's a `1` and doing what I want... Is there no better way?

Comment: what do you mean by "select"?

Comment: seems pretty obvious. What have you tried ? which issue did you encounter ?

Comment: By `Select` I mean change - "utilise them"

Comment: What do you INTEND to do ?

Comment: @VincentPiel I *INTEND* to select the legs and animate them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You loop through the 2d array in reverse...

```
var lowest = [];
var threshold = 6; // find the 6 "lowest" 1's
for(var row=arr.length-1; row>=0; row--)
   for(var col=arr[row].length-1; col>=0; col--)
      if(arr[row][col] == 1 && threshold > 0) {
          threshold--;
          lowest.push({x: col, y: row});
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way :

1) compute per row density = number of black pixel per row
    put this data inside a new 1D array.

2) decide where you consider it is leg or not (with a treshold possibly,
or a relative threshold (ex: less than 30% mean value of non-null rows ...) ).

3) push all (x,y) values in the 'leg' rows.

This will avoid lots of small points 'eating' the pixel threshold
before you come to the body of the monster.